# Why I am getting "'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found."

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I am trying to up my application but I am getting 
"A component required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found."

I have tried the solution  given in the other questions. But none of them is working for me.

** Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface  UserRepository  extends JpaRepository< RegistrationModel, Long>
{

}
```

** Controller.java**

```
     @RestController
     @RequestMapping("bibliophile")
     public class RegistrationController {

        RegistrationController() {

    }


      @Autowired    
     UserRepository user;

    @RequestMapping(value = "registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration( @RequestBody  RegistrationModel request) {
        // request.getURI();
        user.save(request);
        return "Hello I am working";
    }

}
```

**SpringApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value="com.ajtas.bib")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class) 
public class BibliophilerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BibliophilerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

** Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.company.ajtas</groupId>
    <artifactId>udemy-spring-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bibliophiler</name>
    <description>Bibliophiler</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml file as well?

Comment: Or build.gradle

Comment: @Shahzeb I have added the pom.xml. I think all the dependencies are already in place.

Answer (score 0):

Along with hibernate entry in pom.xml, try adding hibernate connection properties in spring boot application.properties file